# Connection aborted (Permission denied) on Permission denied while being root

Tags: docker

I'm running this command

```
docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock --rm chenzj/dfimage faeeab5e90e9
```

but I'm getting

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/entrypoint.py", line 54, in <module>
    my_obj = MainObj()
  File "/root/entrypoint.py", line 15, in __init__
    self._get_image(argv[-1])
  File "/root/entrypoint.py", line 26, in _get_image
    imgs = self.cli.images()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docker/api/image.py", line 40, in images
    res = self._result(self._get(self._url("/images/json"), params=params),
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docker/utils/decorators.py", line 47, in inner
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docker/client.py", line 139, in _get
    return self.get(url, **self._set_request_timeout(kwargs))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 515, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 502, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 612, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 490, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', error(13, 'Permission denied'))
```

**What strikes me is I'm getting this error as root.**

I tried to set /var/run/docker.sock to 777 but still I'm getting Permission denied. 
Any idea what's causing this ?

( Docker is running in throwaway virtual machine in WMware )

Comment: If you run this command `curl -s --unix-sock /var/run/docker.sock http:/v1.30/images/json` do you get a json list of your images?

Comment: yes. 
[root@localhost ~]# curl -s --unix-sock /var/run/docker.sock http:/v1.30/images/json
[{"Containers":-1,"Created":1580366639,"Id":"sha256:faeeab5e90e98994964d35d0388a7dfb1d09d9b6b502530acd03aa211e5e04c1","Labels":{"maintainer":"Jupyter Project <jupyter@googlegroups.com>"},"ParentId":"","RepoDigests":["docker.io/jupyter/datascience-notebook@sha256:80731b3007a72662aa63982db4dad5262af171b275ab7da899b 
...

Answer (score 0):

We need to specify the .sock file as well while we are trying to list the images and I believe that's a little hard with the requests module. 
I'd recommend having a look at this module instead [here](https://pypi.org/project/requests-unixsocket/)